# Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig | Prime on demand Nvidia card

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia

I have a Lenovo G580 computer with intel CPU and a Nvidia 610M GPU. Running Linux Lite OS (Ubuntu based).
I would like to use Nvidia prime to run programs with the GPU.

I installed some packages about Nvidia drivers, version 390 according to [this page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx).
With the Nvidia X Server Settings I can switch to on demand mode. On th UI there is only one settings for prime, no mention about the GPU settings.

My problem is that when the on demand mode is enable, many programs (games and glx debug programs) throw this error : (even without asking to use GPU)

```
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

I know there is other posts like mine on internet however I can't understand the problem or identify a missing package on my computer. Have you already install prime on this GPU ? I can send logs or system info if needed.